# output list element with more occurs in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to write a query which gives has output the element of a list which occurs more. I don't want to use the assert predicate.

I write down this:

```
count([],_,0).
count([H|T],H,X):-
    count(T,H,X2),
    X is X2 + 1.
count([_|T],H,X):-
    count(T,H,X).

ff(_,[A],A).

ff(L,[X|T],X):-
    ff(L,T,X2),
    count(L,X,C1),
    count(L,X2,C2),
    C1 > C2.

ff(L,[H|T],X):-
    ff(L,T,X),
    count(L,H,C1),
    count(L,X,C2),
    C1 =< C2.

find_element(L,X):-
    ff(L,L,X).
```

But it gives me in output always the first element of the list. For example:

> ?-find_element([a,b,c,b,d],X).
>
> X = a

Comment: Can you post some tried inputs and resulting outputs?

Comment: *I don't want to use the `assert` predicate.*. That's good! Using the `assert` predicate would be inappropriate for this problem. `find_element` isn't a very good name for what it seems like you want to do. Do you mean you want a predicate `duplicate_element(X, List)` if `X` occurs more than once in `List`?

Comment: Nope, I want to output the element which has the highest occurs in the list.
For example if I have [a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,d,d] it will output 'c'.

Comment: The clause `count([_|T],H,X):-
    count(T,H,X).` will succeed even if `_ = H`, so you need to makes sure the head of the list is not unifiable with `H` in that clause to keep it mutually exclusive with the prior predicate clause.

Comment: `count` is working fine , by testing it all the samples are givingi a good output.

Comment: You were right, by doing the debug I saw how it was choosing the second count declared. Thanks lurker!

Answer (score 1):

Using SWI prolog, a quick implementation could be:

```
compute([],_,[]).
compute([H|T],List,[HS|TS]):-
    occurrences_of_term(H, List, Occ),
    HS = Occ,
    compute(T,List,TS).

max_occ(List,Occurrences,Value):-
    length(List,N),
    length(Support,N),
    compute(List,List,Support),
    max_list(Support,Occurrences),
    nth1(Index,Support,Occurrences),
    nth1(Index,List,Value),!.
```

The predicates `occurrences_of_term/3`, `max_list/2` and `nth1/3` are also present in ECLiPSe prolog as `occurrences/3`, `maxlist/2` and `nth1/3`.

Some queries:

```
?-max_occ([1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,3,2,2],Occ,Val).
Occ = 6, Val = 2.

?-max_occ([1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2],Occ,Val).
Occ = 6, Val = 1.
```

Comment: It works fine, probablly the best way to do that. But what is wrong in my code? My goal is really understand why I'm wrong instead of the solution itself.